# What is the difference between whole grain wheat and whole wheat?

Tags: language, wheat, grains, wholewheat

I am somewhat confused on the concept of whole grain wheat vs whole wheat. The product in question is "Triscuit" biscuits. The manufacturer does not know so I thought I would put it online. Maybe there is a wheat guru out there.

By the way the *ingredient label* says  whole grain wheat BUT underneath the logo is "**White winter wheat**". So technically we have potentially three different animals running around. They are *whole grain wheat, whole wheat, white winter wheat* and short of visiting the factory and walking through the manufactring process this may be an impossible mystery to solve.

Comment: Could you please add a photo or two? I think this is actually solvable.

Comment: @Stephie. Thank you There is an interesting article in the Answer section. Although it does not address the soft winter wheat mystery I can go with that and assume it's whole wheat. Grains are more complicated than meets the eye. Again thank you for your offer next time I will try to include iphone images of the product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this article](https://www.ars.usda.gov/plains-area/gfnd/gfhnrc/docs/news-2013/wheat-the-whole-grain-story/), it appears that "whole wheat" is a more restrictive term than "whole grain":

> Whole wheat flour is made by milling 100 percent of the kernel into a powder.  Very similar whole grain products are made by recombining the separated milling fractions in the proportions originally present in the whole kernel.  These are similar in appearance.  Both are good sources of dietary fiber.

From the ingredient name "whole grain wheat" on the back of the Triscuit box, it looks like they are going the "recombining the separated milling fractions" way.  Probably since they can optimize storage of each different fraction and/or purchase them separately when the price is advantageous.

Comment: thank you .!  that is a pretty awesome article and I never would have guessed.

Comment: Addtionally 'white winter wheat' is a specific variety of wheat. So there is no conflict with the other two definitions here.

Comment: From what I understand, 100 wheat kernel products tend to a have a significantly shorter shelf life due to the germ oil going rancid. So being able to keep the fiber but not the oil will give most of the benefits of whole grain while being able to store it just like white flour.

Comment: Triscuits are not made from flour, they're made from shredded wheat, that is, wheat grains that are steamed and then pressed through a roller.  I suppose it's possible that the wheat kernels are pearled (to remove the bran) and then additional bran is added, but I wouldn't assume such.

Comment: It makes sense.  Thank youThat might also explain the taste now that I think about it. A little like salty  nabisco shredded wheat biscuits.

Answer (score 1):

These terms "whole wheat" and "whole grain" vary based upon local laws, but these are the general definitions…

- **"Whole grain"** flour contains the whole grain — all parts of the grain — milled as is. None of the bran, germ and endosperm have not been removed. With all the bran and germ, this whole grain flour has a greater fiber content and provides a deeper flavor to breads. When baking, if the whole grain is not milled finely enough, and if the bran in the flour is not hydrated enough, the bran may cause dough not to rise as well as another dough blended with a higher amount of "white" flour. All "whole grain" flours are also "whole wheat" flours.
- **"Whole wheat"** flour starts with the whole grain but may have the bran and germ removed during milling and then has some (or most) of it reintroduced. Often the germ (which contains oil and can go rancid) is not reintroduced in order to make the flour more shelf-stable. Whole wheat flour in Canada may have up to 5% of the grain removed.

The indication of "white" or "red" color refers to the color of the bran (exterior layer) of the kernel. Red has a higher protein content than white.

The time of year (eg. "winter") refers to the time of year the wheat was harvested.

I'm a baker who makes 100% whole grain sourdough bread using [this flour](https://centralmilling.com/product/high-protein-100-whole-wheat-flour-hi-pro-fine/). Notice how many different ways that this flour is described on the page and on the packaging.

Check out these resources:

- ["Hard Red Wheat vs. Hard White Wheat
  " from Bob's Red Mill](https://www.bobsredmill.com/blog/healthy-living/hard-red-wheat-vs-hard-white-wheat/)
- ["Wheat flour" page on wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_flour)

Comment: Wow...wheat and bread is a very interesting and rich topic.  Thank you for all the fine details I would have never have found out on my own.